# How to XMLHttpRequest in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a variable to the server, using `XMLHttpRequest`.

I tested it on local on a non-Wordpress file and it works. 
But on production, on my Wordpress file, the `onreadystatechange AJAX status` doesn't get to `200`.

Is there anything I need to be aware when XMLHttpRequesting in Wordpress?

```
<script>
params = "parameter=" + value;
request.open("POST", "../myfile.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            if (this.responseText != null)
            {
                console.log('Request completed');
            }
            else console.log("Ajax error: No data received")
        }
        else console.log("Ajax error: " + request.statusText );
    }
};
request.send( params );

// 'request' is 'XMLHttpRequest()' or 'ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")'
// depending on browser
</script>
```

To create the code I followed [the 2nd example](http://lpmj.net/1stedition/18.php) of my O'Reilly book.

Any suggestion'll be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You mentioned that you're not getting a 200. What status code *are* you getting?

Comment: That's where is odd: `request.statusText` is empty... no value is thrown.

Comment: Note, if I run `request.status` instead of `request.statusText` I get `0`.

Comment: At this point it'd be great to know how to debug differently... any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: I solved the problem using this on a new version of my theme. Everything works fine. Probably the fact that I'm not using anymore the boilerplate htaccess for WP helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately there is nothing wrong with this script.

I think it was due to the work frame I was using ([Roots](http://www.rootstheme.com/) theme for Wordpress).
I change it for [Handcrafted](http://randyjensenonline.com/thoughts/handcrafted-wp-starter-theme/) and I solved the problem.